# Pandas function pandas.read_sql_table() returns a DataFrame with the values in the wrong order

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get a DataFrame from a PostgreSQL table using the following code:

```
import pandas
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@server/database")
table = pandas.read_sql_table(con=engine, table_name= "table_name", schema= "schema")
```

Suppose the database table primary key goes from 1 to 100, the Data Frames first column will go like 50 to 73, then 1 to 49, the 73 to 100. I've tried adding a chunk_size value to see if that made a difference and got the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically SQL tables have no order and the same applies to queries, unless explicitly defined using `ORDER BY`. Some DBMS, but not PostgreSQL<sup>1</sup>, may use a clustered index and store rows physically in order, but that does not guarantee that a SELECT returns rows in that order without using `ORDER BY`. For example parallel execution plans throw all expectations about query results matching physical order in the bin. Note that DBMS can use for example indexes or other information to fetch rows in order without having to sort, so ordering by a primary key should not add too much of an overhead.

Either sort the data in Python as shown in the other answer, or use `read_sql_query()` instead and pass a query with a specified order:

```
table = pandas.read_sql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM schema.table_name ORDER BY some_column",
    con=engine)
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: PostgreSQL has a `CLUSTER` command that clusters the table based on an index, but it is a one-time operation.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK databases don't always return values in order by primary key. You can sort in pandas:

```
table.sort_values(by=['id'])
```